# I have a few function overloads, each of which takes a different subclass; how do I check which function to use for a given object?

Tags: c++

So I have different `IsIntersecting()` functions, each taking a different combination of Colliders; e.g.:

```
bool IsIntersecting(CircleCollider& coll1, CircleCollider& coll2)
{
    //blah
}

bool IsIntersecting(BoxCollider& coll1, CircleCollider& coll2)
{
    //more blah
}
```

where `BoxCollider` and `CircleCollider` both derive from `Collider`.  Say I have a game object, which has a member variable:

```
Collider _collider;
```

How do I make sure that the right intersection function is called for that collider; i.e. that a function involving a `BoxCollider` is called if the collider is of that type, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use a virtual function in `Collider` and have each Collidier override it.

Comment: I was thinking about that.  I suppose I could try it, but I would still have the issue of picking WHICH function to use, because subclass will still need several overloads o the function; the code for a box colliding with a circle is different to that of box vs box.  So I'll have just shifted the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Take a look at the "Visitor Pattern" for inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). 
Unfortunately C++ does not provide multiple dispatch (only single dispatch) and it is [discussed](http://www.stroustrup.com/multimethods.pdf).

You can find a way around using **dynamic_cast** with something like :

```
bool IsIntersecting(Collider& coll1, CircleCollider& coll2) {
  if (CircleCollider* circle_collider = dynamic_cast<CircleCollider*>(&coll1)) {
    // do what you need 1
  else if (BoxCollider* box_collider = dynamic_cast<BoxCollider*>(&coll1)) {
   // do what you need 2
  }
}
```

On the wiki article they also mention other alternatives such as using the visitor pattern or pointer-to-method lookup table.

Or maybe a better idea : redesign your code to avoid such complications.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the help!  I'll definitely try to restructure my code to avoid this issue, but if I can't think of a way to do so, then I'll try your other suggestions!